# EDA and Attribute selection

Tags: r, feature-selection, model-selection

I have a dataset regarding traffic-violations. The attributes are as follows:

```
'data.frame':   891394 obs. of  32 variables:
 $ subagency              : Factor w/ 8 levels "1st District, Rockville",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ description            : Factor w/ 8423 levels "#3 RT FLAT TIRE",..: 705 3394 4491 705 7753 705 705 705 621 3393 ...
 $ location               : Factor w/ 143973 levels "#3 EAST DIAMOND AVE",..: 124012 124012 99785 124012 76369 76369 124012 76369 132871 76369 ...
 $ accident               : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ belts                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ personal_injury        : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ property_damage        : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ fatal                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ commercial_license     : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hazmat                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ commercial_vehicle     : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ alcohol                : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ work_zone              : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ search_conducted       : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ search_outcome         : Factor w/ 5 levels "Arrest","Citation",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ search_reason_for_stop : Factor w/ 707 levels "10-303(a)","10-305(a)",..: 360 360 479 360 360 360 360 360 362 360 ...
 $ state                  : Factor w/ 65 levels "AB","AK","AL",..: 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 58 25 25 ...
 $ vehicletype            : Factor w/ 28 levels "01 - Motorcycle",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ year                   : num  2005 2005 2008 2018 2016 ...
 $ make                   : Factor w/ 2715 levels ",AZDA",";NISSAN",..: 883 883 71 883 883 883 883 1038 881 1390 ...
 $ model                  : Factor w/ 12114 levels "-","(SW) PASSAT",..: 1042 1042 10836 10155 2218 2218 1042 4653 3362 10562 ...
 $ color                  : Factor w/ 26 levels "BEIGE","BLACK",..: 13 13 25 13 13 13 2 25 2 2 ...
 $ violation_type         : Factor w/ 2 levels "Citation","Warning": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ charge                 : Factor w/ 900 levels "10-303(a)","10-303(f)",..: 529 146 657 529 78 529 529 529 531 128 ...
 $ article                : Factor w/ 4 levels "BR","Maryland Rules",..: 4 4 4 4 2 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ contributed_to_accident: Factor w/ 2 levels "False","True": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ race                   : Factor w/ 6 levels "ASIAN","BLACK",..: 1 1 6 1 3 3 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ gender                 : Factor w/ 3 levels "F","M","U": 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ driver_city            : Factor w/ 6068 levels "-",".","00","10019 VANDERBILT CIR",..: 4591 4591 4591 625 5006 5006 3468 1691 4591 5006 ...
 $ driver_state           : Factor w/ 65 levels "AB","AK","AL",..: 25 25 25 42 25 25 25 58 25 25 ...
 $ dl_state               : Factor w/ 68 levels "AB","AK","AL",..: 27 27 27 43 27 27 27 61 27 27 ...
 $ arrest_type            : Factor w/ 10 levels "A - Marked Patrol",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The target variable is violation_type.
How do I select the relevant features? I tried to use Boruta package in R but it is not working. I used the chi-square test as there are many categorical attributes.

What models should I use for this kind of data?

Comment: I think you should use some domain knowledge and start with a subset of features and a baseline model. See if they are significant. Then increase the number of features.